# Discover serial ports in C#

Tags: c#, .net, usb, registry, serial-port

I'm writing an application that communicates by sending bytes to the USB port. I'd like to allow the user to choose the port and to do that, I use `SerialPort.GetPortNames()`. Unfortunately, it returns an empty array. The method supposedly reads the registry for data (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM), but the SERIALCOMM directory is missing. When I run the program on Linux, it lists my four USB ports, as expected. How can I fix the registry/discover the ports in a different way?

Comment: The simple explanation is that your machine simply doesn't have any serial ports.  Not all USB device drivers emulate a serial port.  Or you may have a device whose driver isn't installed correctly.  You can double-check with Control Panel + Device Manager.  Ask questions about the specific device you are using at superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` are the correct method to discover serial ports. But if you are using Windows 7, I think it could be issues with permissions on the registry keys this method lists. I found a post which describe this problem at [Microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lt-LT/w7itprogeneral/thread/e84cb844-9970-42fd-abac-d5616ec791e2).

Comment: I am using Windows 7 indeed. But when I open the regedit as admin, I still don't see the directory.

Comment: Also, the solution creates the directory empty.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Management Objects  to query available COM ports. The interesting tables are:

- [MSSerial_PortName](http://www.scriptinternals.de/new/us/default.asp?WMI_MSSerial_PortName) in root\WMI
- [MSWmi_PnPInstanceNames](http://www.scriptinternals.de/new/us/default.asp?WMI_MSWmi_PnPInstanceNames) in root\WMI
- [Win32_PnPEntity](http://www.scriptinternals.de/new/us/default.asp?WMI_Win32_PnPEntity) in root\CIMV2

You can explore these namespaces in the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8572), and generate VBScript/VB/C# code.

Answer (score 1):

`SerialPort.GetPortNames()` returns the list of COM ports install on the machine, not USB ports.  I don't think Windows will provide you with a list of USB ports, only USB devices that are available.

Despite the name "Universal Serial Bus", they are not "Serial Ports" in the convential meaning.