# Serial port code in C++ not working. USB to RS232

Tags: c++, serial-port

I have a RS232 to USB convertor, drivers are installed. I already have a GUI program to change my chops configuration and it works fine.

My question is, I wrote a code in VS2008 in C++ to find all the COM ports using:

```
SerialPort::GetPortNames()
```

My problem is that it doesn't return anything. No COM ports at all. When I check the device on device manager, it gives me 3 COM ports for the device. Cnca1 and Cncab1 on ports 10 and 36 respectively and both of them are emulator ports and a USB port on COM3, if I run the GUI program, it says that the device is in COM3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624041/discover-serial-ports-in-c-sharp Yup, it's C#, but the solution is likely the same.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, i will test this. i searched alot but didn't see this one. probably cuz i was using c++ as my main search area.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was exactly the admin access to registry.